# jQuery scrollTop() method not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have the following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navtoTop').click(function(){
           $("html").scrollTop( $("#topofthePage").offset().top );
    }); 
});
```

where 'navtoTop' is the class of the button(something like 'Back to top') which has the fixed position in the bottom-left of the page and 'topofthePage' is the id of the `<div>` at the most top of my page.

I have even tried this

```
$('.navtoTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
});
```

Here is the html code

```
<body>
    <div id="topofthePage"></div>
    ...
    ...
    <img src="navtoTop.png" class="navtoTop">   
</body>
```

I don't know what is going wrong but this is not working. Will someone explain and give a good solution?

Ask me the detail of code if you want.

Comment: Show us your html code

Comment: check out i have updated the que...

Comment: I think you already have an answer that should work  ... another alternative to `$.scrollTop()` usage could be modifying the `window.location` to use a hash fragment. Like this: `window.location += '#topofthePage';`

Comment: awesome that worked but can we implement this with animate for a smooth scrolling.

Comment: Nope, we need a different approach ... just posted a answer, see below

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to use `window` instead of `html`:

```
$(window).scrollTop( $("#topofthePage").offset().top );
```

Note that `window` should not be enclosed in quotes as i'ts an object and not a tag.

Comment: He is right. you should use $(window) instead $("html"). This statement will scroll body scrollbar.

Comment: + I saw some codebases where it is `$('body')`. It should be replaced by `$(window)`.

Comment: I just realized I never thanked you for this. Thanks @taxicala. Anyways I'm into Android App Development now. LOL.

Comment: $(window).scrollTop( $("#topofthePage").offset().top ); gave me an error saying `$(...).offset() is not a function`. So, apparently, `$('#topofthePage').offsetTop` might work

Answer (score 7):

A common scrollTo issue is having overflow set on the "html, body" element in css. Rarely mentioned when having scrolling/animating issues on html/body elements and can end up in excessive over-engineering.

**If overflow needs to be set, put it on the body element only**. Not both html,body.

It is also a good habit to use a data-* attribute in place of classes or IDs in your html. This gets you in the habit of separating styles from code. Consider this to make your life easier in the future:

**Create Reusable Scroll Function**

```
scrollioreceiver = function(sender) {

  $(sender).on({
    click: sentFrom
  });

  function sentFrom(){
    var dataMine = $(this).attr('data-sender'),
        dataSend = $('[data-receiver="'+dataMine+'"]');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(dataSend).offset().top - 70
    }, 800, function() {
        // if you need a callback function
    });
  }
}
```

Create data attributes to html elements (data-name is arbitrary and should make sense):

**ADD HTML LINK**

```
<a data-sender="ScrollToMatch">Link To Click To Scroll To Match Attribute</a>
```

**ADD HTML ELEMENT**

```
<div data-receiver="ScrollToMatch">Scrolls To This Element</div>
```

**VERIFY CSS** 
» overflow added to "html,body" won't work

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

**INIT FUNCTION ON READY**
» initialize on doc ready with attribute name selector to create flexibility on multiple calls

```
scrollioreceiver('[data-sender]');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my instance an "overflow-x: hidden" on a parent DIV (not body or html) was preventing the scroll from happening. For anyone else that runs into this issue: check your parent DIVs!

Answer (score 3):

You already got an answer on this. But, since you also want a smooth scrolling, consider the following alternative:

```
$('.navtoTop').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#topofthePage').offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navtoTop').click(function(){
          $(window).scrollTop()
          $("window").scrollTop( $("#topofthePage").offset().top );
    }); 
});
```