# jQuery scrollTop() method does not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to make a "Scroll to top" button, and I have already written the HTML, CSS, and the main script.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Наверх</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });
});
```

and the CSS

```
.scrollup{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    opacity:0.3;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    right:100px;
    display:none;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background: url('icon_top.png') no-repeat;
}
```

But for some reason, `.scrollTop()` the method does not work. Even if I try to call `alert()` (while other jQuery methods work fine)

P.S. In jsfiddle this code works

Comment: any errors in your console on the browser? If it works in fiddle there might be an issue with your jquery not being included

Comment: I have no errors

Comment: Yes. It didn't help

Comment: And != 0 also did not help

Comment: "In jsfiddle this code works" means you have some other code conflicting with this, so the best we can do is guess at what's going on.  A guess: in your site is `.scrollup` added to the DOM dynamically, after the above code runs?

Comment: @Aleksandr see the updated answer, and lets try

Comment: I think that other scripts block this one. Because I tried to call a normal alert () before </body>, but it closed automatically, and did not stop loading the page

Comment: Well, I know that I'm newbie, but it was just a conflict of scripts... But thanks to everyone for help ;)

Comment: reffer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277323/jquery-scrolltop-method-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make sure this code does not conflict with any script then

Try to the following

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() != 0)
```

instead of

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100)
```

See this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {  
        if ($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
        } else { 
            $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
        }
    }); 
    $('.scrollup').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
    });
});
```

make sure not conflict to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jquery first and later you can call its functions.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
    }
  });
  $('.scrollup').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 600);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
<style>
.scrollup {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 100px;
  /* display:none; */
  /* text-indent:-9999px; */
  background: url('icon_top.png') no-repeat;
}
</style>


<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg">
<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg">
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Наверх</a>
```